# How to display the image of instead of empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const customImage = tmpl.customImage ? tmpl.customImage.map(c => c.url) : "https://yourl img here";
```

here `tmpl.customImage` is getting empty array[] so i want to display a default image instead of empty. But it is not fetching to default image it is showing empty...

Please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Try `tmpl.customImage.length > 0 ? ...`

Comment: FYI, arrays are always [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), even if they are empty.

Comment: Do note that your conditional statement results either in an array or a string. Having a conditional statement return different data types is prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking it length?

```
const customImage = tmpl.customImage.length ? tmpl.customImage.map(c => c.url) : "https://yourl img here";
```

Answer (score 0):

use instead of that:
`const customImage = tmpl.customImage.length ? tmpl.customImage.map(c => c.url) : "https://yourl img here";`

Answer (score 0):

give your image url link in that array make that variable and use res.render to render your file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Is tmpl.customImage already an array, then why assign an array to customImage ?

You can handle the empty array here:

```
tmpl.customImage.push({"url":"https://yourimghere"}); // add to the end
const customImage = tmpl.customImage.shift(); // take from the top
```